# How to solve the CORS issue when the endpoint doesn't accept OPTIONS method?

Tags: angular, .htaccess, magento, ionic2

I'm building mobile client apps for easily manage Magento E-commerce store, I;m using the Token Based authentication [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html) , I'm using ionic2 for my mobile framework.

My problem is, The angular HTTP is sent `OPTIONS` request instead of `POST` to `/V1/integration/admin/token`   endpoint that produce `400 bad request` because the endpoint doesn't support the  `OPTIONS` method.

here my code :

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { BaseConfig } from '../../config';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class AuthProvider {
    
      public data: any;
    
      public option: any;
    
      constructor(public http: Http) {
        console.log('Hello AuthProvider Provider');
    
      }
    
      login(creds: any) {
        
        let headers = new Headers({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
    
        let option = new RequestOptions({
          headers: headers,
        });
    
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          this.data = this.http.post(BaseConfig.base_url + 'integration/admin/token', creds, option)
            .map(res => res.json())
              .subscribe((data) => {
                resolve(this.data);
              },
              (error) => {
                resolve(this.data);
              }
            );
        });
    
      }  
  
   }
```

I also including the CORS header on my .htaccess

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type"
```

so the real issue is how to prevent angular http requested with `OPTIONS` method (i think impossible because is preflighted request).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not change the backend to accept `OPTIONS` requests? `CORS` requests are not an angular thing, but a browser thing. It's how the CORS standard mandates the browser to behave.

Comment: so, should I remove the custom headers added to .htaccess?

Comment: There is no way to avoid the preflight in this case if you’re making the request directly to that endpoint from frontend JavaScript running in a browser — not as long at the endpoint requires the Content-Type for the POST to be either "Content-Type:application/json" or "Content-Type:application/xml", which it does according to http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html. Your only options are to put some proxy in between your frontend JavaScript call and the server, or else just do it all in your backend code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason, but i think you should try it in the real device.

Comment: ente siapa ya..?

Comment: Thanks your solution solved my problem :D I don'y know why, but deploying to real device did the trick....!

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own server in between (like a proxy) that (doesn't require CORS when the HTML content is loaded from the same URL+port)
or you can use JSONP which is quite limited though.

Otherwise you'll need to configure the server to support `OPTIONS`.  The `OPTIONS` request is a preflight request and the browser won't make the `POST` request if it doesn't get the expected response from the `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: I try to using Chrome extension to do that, but not solve the problem,,,

Comment: I haven't tried the chrome extensions myself yet to work around CORS issues, but I have heard it works. Not idea why it doesn't for you.

Answer (score 0):

May be below example can get you the thing what you want.

```
login(creds: any) {

        let headers = new Headers({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        });

        let option = new RequestOptions({
          headers: headers,
          withCredentials:true
        });

        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          this.data = this.http.post(BaseConfig.base_url + 'integration/admin/token', creds, option)
            .map(res => res.json())
              .subscribe((data) => {
                resolve(this.data);
              },
              (error) => {
                resolve(this.data);
              }
            );
        });

      }
```